# Find broken pixel in OLED

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, webcam, emgucv

I have OLED display and webcam Logitech C920 HD. What algorithms can I use for find broken pixels? Now I thresholding for finding broken pixels, but result is no good.

Comment: Please add details, perhaps code too to the question. And of course the problem you face when using said code...

Comment: if you are looking to find dead pixels on a monitor just go to http://jasonfarrell.com/misc/deadpixeltest.php

Comment: @Saint I believe OP wants to find dead pixels from camera.
(Because, it's not related to OpenCV otherise, is it?)

Comment: @SuINR Please explain what you mean by 'result is no good'.

Answer (score 0):

OP does not make clear if he's interested in locating dead pixel on monitor or camera. If the latter, in most cases I've dealt with, dead pixels are read as fixed ("stuck") values in the sensor raster. Often their value will be at one end of the range, i.e. 0, or 0xff for 8-bit sensors, or 0x0fff for 12-bit sensors, etc.

So they are really easy to find if you have access to the raw Bayer mosaic from the sensor: just take a few images with different lighting (e.g. changing the exposure time) and look for pixels whose value does not change across the series of images.

This method does not work (or does not work so well) if the device only lets you access the demosaiced image, because one stuck pixel value will affect the values of several pixels in the demosaiced image.